# Adding several custom subviews throughout UITableView (settings panel)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a slide-out UIView which is acting as a settings panel. The view has a container with a table view controller within it. The table view itself has about 6 groups of static cells which represent various options. There are several UIButtons in each cell, and depending on the group, they have different behavior. I've created a separate custom UIView subclass which handles the drawing of the buttons in each group. When this panel is first loaded, I'm creating a dictionary of dictionaries for each group's buttons & a dictionary of dictionaries (with matching key paths) for each group's custom views.

The problem is that the custom views only seem to line up at the top part of the panel. When I scroll down further to the bottom part of my panel, the button views are not lined up. For the life of me I can't seem to figure this out. Here's pictures of the panel:

[image: Top of panel (working as expected)]
[image: Bottom of panel (bad things are happening)]

Here is the code I'm using to initialize the settings & layout the custom subviews when the panel loads (in the settings panel table view controller class):

```
- (void)initializeSettings
    {
        self.buttonStates = nil; // A dictionary of dictionaries with all button states within the panel
        self.buttonViews = nil;  // A dictionary of dictionaries with all button views (same keyPaths as self.buttonStates).
        NSMutableDictionary *buttonStates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *buttonViews = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSArray *btnGroupNames = [self btnGroupNames]; // Array of button group names.
        NSArray *btnArrays = [self btnArrays]; // An array of arrays with all buttons.
        for(int i = 0; i < [btnArrays count]; i++){
            NSArray *outerArray = [btnArrays objectAtIndex: i];
            NSString *outerKey = [btnGroupNames objectAtIndex: i];
            NSMutableDictionary *innerDicV = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSMutableDictionary *innerDicS = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            for(UIButton *btn in outerArray){
                NSString *innerKey = [btn.titleLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                ButtonSelectionView *bsv  = [[ButtonSelectionView alloc] initWithFrame: btn.frame];
                bsv.alpha = 0.0;
                bsv.opaque = NO;
                [[btn superview] addSubview: bsv];
                [[btn superview] bringSubviewToFront: btn];
                [innerDicV addEntriesFromDictionary: @{ innerKey : bsv }];
                [innerDicS addEntriesFromDictionary: @{ innerKey : NOT_SELECTED }];
            }
            [buttonViews setValue: innerDicV forKey: outerKey];
            [buttonStates setValue: innerDicS forKey: outerKey];
        }
        self.buttonViews = buttonViews;
        self.buttonStates = buttonStates;
        self.previousButtonStates = nil;
        self.settingsLoaded = YES;
    }
```

Side note: The dictionaries are lazily instantiated. Also, I've tried calling this function from viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, & viewDidLayoutSubviews but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and thank you!

Comment: Okay, maybe to simply the question: At what point do UIButtons know what their frame is inside of a UITableViewCell? How might I go about obtaining all of the frames of all UIButtons (even ones outside of the visible view) as I positioned them in IB? Enumerating through the outlet collections seems to give me the same result as pictured above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this one out, as well. Because I already had wired up outlets to my buttons in IB, I realized I always have an active reference to the UIButton's frame property. I just needed to reset the frame of the custom view to the current button frame at the point of initialization/animation. So I changed the above code to add a 3rd NSDictionary that references each button by the same keypath as the other two dictionaries. Then, when I needed the custom UIView to change/appear, I referenced the button in that dictionary for the frame value:

```
- (void)initializeSettings
    {
        self.buttonStates = nil; // A dictionary of dictionaries with all button states within the panel
        self.buttonViews = nil;  // A dictionary of dictionaries with all button views (same keyPaths as self.buttonStates).
        NSMutableDictionary *buttonStates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *buttonViews = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *buttons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSArray *btnGroupNames = [self btnGroupNames];
        NSArray *btnArrays = [self btnArrays];
        for(int i = 0; i < [btnArrays count]; i++){
            NSArray *outerArray = [btnArrays objectAtIndex: i];
            NSString *outerKey = [btnGroupNames objectAtIndex: i];
            NSMutableDictionary *innerDicV = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSMutableDictionary *innerDicS = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSMutableDictionary *innerDicB = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            for(UIButton *btn in outerArray){
                NSString *innerKey = [btn.titleLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                ButtonSelectionView *bsv  = [[ButtonSelectionView alloc] initWithFrame: btn.frame];
                bsv.alpha = 0.0;
                bsv.opaque = NO;
                [[btn superview] addSubview: bsv];
                [[btn superview] bringSubviewToFront: btn];
                [innerDicV addEntriesFromDictionary: @{ innerKey : bsv }];
                [innerDicS addEntriesFromDictionary: @{ innerKey : NOT_SELECTED }];
                [innerDicB addEntriesFromDictionary: @{ innerKey : btn }];
            }
            [buttonViews setValue: innerDicV forKey: outerKey];
            [buttonStates setValue: innerDicS forKey: outerKey];
            [buttons setValue: innerDicB forKey: outerKey];
        }
        self.buttonViews = buttonViews;
        self.buttonStates = buttonStates;
        self.buttons = buttons;
        self.previousButtonStates = nil;
        self.settingsLoaded = YES;
    }
```

And then, when a button was clicked, in my "update UI" method, I added this line of code to reposition the custom Button Selection View:

```
bsv.frame = ((UIButton *)[self.buttons valueForKeyPath: keyPath]).frame;
```

Hopefully that will help someone out with a similar problem. I imagine you can do the same thing programmatically by initializing / storing your button objects & custom view objects in viewDidLayoutSubviews and referencing them the same way when you update your UI.